# How to get actual element position from webpage during css transition in python?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am trying to speed up a test by not waiting for a css transition to happen, but rather have a `WebDriverWait` handle the task for me. Currently it looks to me that `lambda elem: elem.location["x"]` immediately returns the end value after it begins rather than the actual value.

How can I access the location of the element correctly while it is in a css animation?